# Apache, 2 websites on remote server

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I need to host two websites on my remote web server. It must look like `ip.ip.ip.ip/site1` and `ip.ip.ip.ip/site2`.

How to do that on Apache and Ubuntu?

Comment: If you just want that configuration you can run one instance of apache with those two folders as subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Use *alias* for aliasing directories.

So just add to the end of apache configuration file something like this :

```
alias /site1 /home/something/application1
alias /site2 /home/something/application2
```